# не запускается приложение, если задано свойство SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте! Хочу включить проверку орфографии в компоненте
вот xaml код

```
<Window x:Class="WordsTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WordsTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Проверить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="505" Click="button_Click"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="270" Width="500" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True">
        <SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
            <sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,dictionary.lex</sys:Uri>
        </SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
    </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

но при компиляции проекта появляется ошибка
`Exception from HRESULT: 0xC1311010`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Первая [ссылка](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d979cb4-70d6-4bd4-8689-5d0f920cad2b/exception-from-hresult-0xc1311010?forum=wpf) в гугле. Лень?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сделал. результат такой же. да и ошибка другая у меня

Comment: Попробуйте `pack://application:,,,/dictionary.lex`